# Add new row data in PowerBI table and persist it to the source

Tags: powerbi

This is an open-ended questions, as in I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is.
Is there a way/process/workflow you've used in order to take user-provided input from within PowerBI and persist it in the source tables?
Ie. Can I use PBI as an interactive GUI in any meaningful way? I realise it's not designed for this kind of job, but bear with me on this. If I didn't have the resources right now to build a separate data admin GUI to change the source file on blob storage, can I use PBI in any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps but I use excel with Power Query. And excel is a kind of GUI for me.
I can write some parametrs and store them in excel file. And applay stored parametrs while runing PQ script. This approach fit me very well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [PowerApps visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual) for Power BI and a PowerApp which writes back to the datasource. The data writeback is easy to be implemented. The difficult part is the update of the report after the data is changed. Obviously it is not practical to use import mode, so DirectQuery is the most logical choice. A `Refresh()` function will be added to the PowerApp's [PowerBIIntegration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/admin/set-up-power-bi-integration) when you create it from within Power BI, which could help you in this case.

Here is one good article to start with - [Using Power Apps in Power BI reports: Enabling writeback](https://shabnamwatson.wpcomstaging.com/2020/02/21/using-power-apps-in-power-bi-reports-enabling-writeback/). Also I recommend this recording on the subject - [Writing back data to PowerBI from your reports](https://sqlmasteracademy.com/course/writing-back-data-to-powerbi-from-your-reports/).